# How to customize appearance of a single tab bar item?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I need middle tab bar item to look different from others. Here is an illustration:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

EDIT: 
All tabs except of middle react on selection in standard way. Only middle tab looks the same when selected.

Comment: I have answer but in objective c. you can set setSelectionIndicatorImage of that tab. You have to make image and set as  setSelectionIndicatorImage of selected tab and for other tabs it is nil or as you want to set

Comment: If you can, please post it as answer in objective-c. I'll try and mark as correct if it works. Thank you for this comment

Comment: ok, I will try to convert it into Swift

Comment: I just convert whole code into Swift, Please solve it if there is any mistake remaining.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try

Comment: Ok Sure, Just reply me back It is working or not

Comment: Is it working for you?

Comment: Hi. It does work. Voted up your answer, but I need a little bit different behaviour. I want middle tab to look like on the picture all the time. It won't react on selection. Other tabs should react in standard way. Thank you for your answer, it helped a lot.

Comment: So just return height in my function as you want. Please approve my answer for others

Comment: I can't mark it as correct because it is an answer on another question. I would confuse others in this case

Comment: So i told you Return your customise height as you want into returnImageofSelectetab() function. Right now height is of tabSize.height, if you want 10 px space from bottom then return tabSize.height-10 in function

Comment: All is ok with height. The problem is that your code sets image to selected tab. I want selection behavior to be standard for all tabs except of third. Third tab is static. Or I got something wrong in your code. It works as I just explained for me

Comment: I think it's not possible with UITabBarController. I am going to find library or to create custom view for tab bar. Thank you for your effort, @JitendraModi

Comment: Yes, It is possible, you have to concentrate what you are doing actually. Please send me demo, i will do it for you

Comment: I did it on Android. Here is how it worked: https://www.youtube.com/edit?o=U&video_id=pV0GGvHOBs4 . The middle button has to launch different viewController on top of current TabBarController

Answer (score 2):

```
Take a subclass of TabbarController.Remember to call  `<UITabBarControllerDelegate>`


    func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        //
        tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = returnImageofSelectetab()
    }

//Method called everytime when you select tab.

    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {

        if tabBarController.tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage == nil {
            print("Starting point delegate: Selection indicator image is nill")
        }
        else {
            print("Starting Point Of delegate: Selection indicator image is available")
        }

//HERE i gave index where I want to set image.
        if tabBarController.selectedIndex == 2 {
            tabBarController.tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = nil
        }
        else {
            tabBarController.tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = returnImageofSelectetab()
        }
        if tabBarController.tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage == nil {
            print("Ending point delegate: Selection indicator image is nill")
        }
        else {
            print("Ending Point Of delegate: Selection indicator image is available")
        }
    }

        func returnImageofSelectetab() -> UIImage {
        //HERE 'img_sel' is YOUR SELECTED IMAGE SET AS BACKGROUND OF YOUR TABBARITEM
            let selTab = UIImage(named: "img_sel")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
            let tabSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width / 5, height: 49)
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(tabSize)
            selTab?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tabSize.width, height: tabSize.height))
            let reSizeImage: UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            return reSizeImage!
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should subclass `UITabBarController` and change the appearance of the third `UITabBarItem` in its `items` array inside `awakeFromNib`.

```
class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        guard let items = tabBar.items else {
            return
        }

        for i in 0 ..< items.count {
            item.image = image
            item.selectedImage = selectedImage

            [...]
        }
    }
}
```